# Computational Complexity of exponentiating

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, computational-complexity

I'm currently studying this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0703061v2.pdf) and I am trying to understand the complexity of the interpolate algorithm, which is supposed to be $O((l+m)^2)$.

So first the algorithm runs in $r$ steps where $r\leq l+m$. So I think the first $(l+m)$ factor comes from this.

Now I guess the most expensive step in the algorithm is the calculation

$$f_0(x,y)=f_0^q(x,y)-\Delta_0^{q-1}f_0(x,y) $$

where the $f^q_0(x,y)$ calculation boils down to calculating $a_i^q$ for some $a_i\in \mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ for an integer $m$ and prime power $q$. Now my questions is what is the complexity of this calculation?

Comment: Is multiplication constant time? If so you can do it $\log q$ time.

Comment: I'm not sure. It does not say so explicitly. What would the complexity be if multiplication is not constant time?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it weren't constant time. If it weren't then there's nothing that can be said in general, it depends on how long it takes.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring for the $\log q$ time algorithm for computing it, by the way.

Comment: Okay so if I assume that multiplication is time constant, $f_0^q(x,y)$ can be calculated in $O(\log(q) (l+m))$ since $f_0(x,y)$ consists of at most $l+m$ terms and each term can be calculated as $a_i ^q$. And then I have not accounted for the subtraction or $\Delta_0^{q-1}$ which is just evaluating $f_0(x_j,y_j)$.

Comment: Raising an element of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ to power $q$ is a special case. You absolutely should **NOT** use *exponentiation_by_squaring* for that. The reason is that this is the Frobenius automorphism, so it is a linear function. Depending on the internal presentation of elements of the field I would either build a look-up-table for the powers of basis elements, or, if using a normal basis presentation, not do anything, because raisiing to power $q$ is then achieved by shifting the coefficients cyclically.